# polymer google-map-marker on-click reference data binding object

Tags: google-maps, firebase, polymer

I have several google-map-marker displayed on map:

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{deviceData}}" as="data">
    <google-map-marker latitude="{{data.lat}}" longitude="{{data.long}}"
        title="{{data.name}}" click-events on-google-map-marker-click="markerClicked"
        icon="/images/icon-0-75x.png">
    </google-map-marker>
  </template>
```

How can I refer to the {{data}} object from within the "markerClicked" event?

```
markerClicked: function(e, detail, sender) {
}
```

I would like to show a paper-card with some details of the data object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution by Ahmad will work but it's not the best way. The reason is because `data-details$="{{data}}"` will serialize the contents of the `data` variable as string attribute value on market elements.

Instead you can [refer to the template elements in event handlers](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/templates#handling-events). Here's how this would work in your example:

```
markerClicked: function(e) {
   var data = e.model.data;
   // do data stuff.!
}
```

The only important bit is that last part of `e.model.data` must match the value of the `as` attribute. If that attribute is omitted, you would write `e.model.item` instead, same as you would use to bind inside the repeated template.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way:

```
<google-map-marker ... data-details$="{{data}}" ... />
```

and add the following in the listener callback

```
markerClicked: function(e, detail, sender) {
    var data = e.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-details');
    // do data stuff.!
}
```